# Ubuntu 20.04 Clamav restore from quarantine

Tags: clamav

I found that Clamav has set in quarantine some files important (libreOffice, Ubuntu Software and other not virus file).
Is there any way to restore all the files from the quarantine?

Comment: They may be false positives. Unless you are using Wine, ClamAV is not worth using. Ubuntu is not *that* vulnerable.

Comment: I agree I uninstalled clamav, but still I can't open those programs

Comment: In case you remember name of any of these files, try `locate filename`, where `filename` is the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This tool helps - https://github.com/Shrizt/clamav-quarantine-recover
Just run:

```
clamav-qrecover ./clamav.log --restore
```